# Call a pointer to a member function passed into a function

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointer-to-member

I am passing a pointer to a member function into a template function. Something like this,

```
    Foo bar; /* bar.baz(...) is a function */
    auto pnt = bar.baz;

    passMmbFunc<...,decltype(pnt)>(...,pnt);
```

The relevant parts of `passMmbFunc` look like this,

```
   template <..., typename D>
   void map(..., D func) {
     ...
     auto ret = func(someVal);
     ...
   }
```

I assumed that the syntax for calling a pointer to a member function is the same as a regular pointer to function but it is not. I get the following error,

```
    error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'func (...)', e.g. '(... ->* func) (...)'
```

From within `passMmbFunc`, how would I call pnt? I know that a pointer to a member function can be called if you have a object of the respective class handy. But since I am passing it as a parameter, that is not the case. So, is there anyway to call a pointer to member function if you only have a pointer and no object?

Comment: You made a wrong assumption.

Comment: The syntax is tripping you up because (as the previous comment suggested) you assumed too much.  You cannot call a pointer to a non-static member function without an object, and the syntax ensures that.

Comment: What would invoking a member function like `size()` or `to_string()` or whatever mean without an instance of the relevant class?

Comment: Ah, I see. Calling the function wouldn't make sense outside the context of an object. So it would work if the member function was static?

Comment: @sguzman If the function is static, then yes, you can call it without an instance of the object.

Comment: @ddriver Turns out my question is a duplicate. I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer-to-member function must be called on an object - it cannot work as a standalone function. Hence your error. `baz` must be called with some `Foo` using either the `.*` or `->*` syntax:

```
auto ptr_to_mem = &Foo::baz;
Foo f, *pf;

ptr_to_mem();        // error
(f.*ptr_to_mem)();   // ok
(pf->*ptr_to_mem()); // ok
```

The way to do this in C++ is to *bind* the pointer-to-member with an object that you will call it with. The standard even provides a function to do that: [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
auto pnt = std::bind(&Foo::baz, bar);
pnt(); // this is the equivalent of bar.baz();
```

One possible source of confusion is that `auto pnt = bar.baz;` will actually do exactly what you want in *Python*. Just not in C++.

Comment: You mean `The way to do this in C++(11)`

Comment: I'd say by now C++11 is old and supported enough to be considered implicit.

Comment: I don't think C++11 is "implicitly" enabled by most compilers as you always have to pass `std=c++11`